# Why is the destructor called here?

Tags: c++

Here's a code i wrote, the sm_string(like std::string) class:

```
class sm_string
{
....
    void _Add(sm_string a)
    {// it adds the string to string(concatenates) and saves result in (*this)
        printf("\n_Add %s %s\n",str,a());
        str = (char*)ReallocSave(str,Len()+a.Len()+1,Len()+1);
        memcpy(str+Len(),a(),a.Len()+1);
    }
    sm_string Add(sm_string a)
    {// it concatenates too, return result,doesnt change (*this)
        printf("\nAdd %s %s\n",str,a());
        sm_string res(str);
        res._Add(a);
        return res;
    }


    sm_string(char* a)      
    {// creates string from char* string
        str = (char*)malloc(strlen(a)+1);
        memcpy(str,a,strlen(a)+1);
        printf("Creating %s\n",str);
    }
    sm_string(int a)        
    {// creates string from int
        char buf[100];
        itoa(a,buf,10);
        str = (char*)malloc(strlen(buf)+1);
        memcpy(str,buf,strlen(buf)+1);
        printf("Creating %s\n",str);
    }
    sm_string()     
    {//creates null string {'\0'}

        str = (char*)malloc(1);
        str[0] = '\0';
        printf("Creating %s\n",str);
    }
    ~sm_string()
    {//frees the pointer
        printf("\nFree of %s\n",str);
        free(str);
    }
.....
};
```

That's the my realloc function(cause normal realloc may lose the content while allocating more memory)

```
void* ReallocSave(void* pointer,int size,int oldsize)
{//realloc, which doesnt loose the memory
    void* _instance = malloc(size);
    memcpy(_instance,pointer,min(size,oldsize));
    free(pointer);
    return _instance;
}
```

It's the main function:

```
...
sm_string a("1");
a._Add(a.Add(3));
printf("%s",a());
...
```

And when i run this i receive an error

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/1IOCn.png]

As you see the destructor of "113" - it's the string from main function - is called twice. At all there's 3 constructors calls and 4 destructors, how can i fix this?

Comment: I don't believe that "normal realloc may lose the content while allocating more memory" is true.

Comment: Why are you using `malloc`, `free`, `memcpy`, and `char*` in C++?

Comment: Use const reference to pass parameters, use const char * to pass string literals

Comment: Where is your copy constructor and `operator=()` ?

Comment: And are we just supposed to close this as a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three?

Comment: I dont think this is an error, but just the deletion of the temporary `res` in your `Add`

Comment: -1 as you have failed to post code sufficient to reproduce.  I don't see your `operator()` which you call.  The `...` is a red flag: learn hoe to post a minimal, complete example.  If you do not know ehat is going wrong, how can you know what to omit?  Easy: omit it, **then test that omitting it kept the same problem alive**.  Repeat until the code is short and describes your problem.  It should work 100% until the error you do not understand occurs.

Answer (score 1):

Just a guess:

Your parameter is a string, not a reference or a pointer of string but a string. Basically when `_Add` is called a copy of `sm_string a` is created on the stack.

The destructor is then called twice on the `a` the variable a in the `_Add` function (which is a copy of the original object) and on the `a` in your main function.

```
void _Add(sm_string a) <= Try to change a with a pointer or a reference
{
    // it adds the string to string(concatenates) and saves result in (*this)
    printf("\n_Add %s %s\n",str,a());
    str = (char*)ReallocSave(str,Len()+a.Len()+1,Len()+1);
    memcpy(str+Len(),a(),a.Len()+1);
}
```

Comment: This might work, but it's really just working around the real bug: the missing copy constructor and assignment operator.